# How to install an old Java version alongside the new one for use in eclipse spring?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I want to install an old Java version alongside the new one for use in eclipse spring. On windows.

I have 1.8 installed. Eclipse picked up 1.8, I set the compliance level to 1.6 but it misses problems like `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.List.sort`.

I downloaded the 1.6 exe installer for windows, but I believe if I run it it will only install 1.6 as the default which is not what I want.

Do you have any hints what the procedure is for installing an old version alongside the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer will eventually ask "Do you also want to install the Java runtime?" Say no. That will leave you with just the Java SDK (which also contains the complete Java runtime). Only the second part of the installation will modify your PATH variable.

If this somehow corrupts your existing Java installation, just install Java 8 again without removing Java 6, first. That will fix it.

You may want to check your PATH variable afterwards to make sure it doesn't contain any junk.

Answer (score 1):

You need JDK 1.6 in your local machine in some drive. In eclipse right click on the project `Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Add Library -> JRE System Library`

Inside `JRE System Library` click on Alternate JRE and choose 1.6 version.
Make Sure you remove the 1.8 library for that project.

This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can install as many JDK versions as you want. You only need to be careful about the paths provided by your OS (check the environment variables and the default Eclipse paths).

Answer (score 0):

In the installation of the JDK I had to deselect the third option "Public JRE" to prevent it from installing more than the JDK and sources.

I then had to play with the JRE System Library properties to make it find the new JRE.

In the pom.xml I edited the maven-compiler-plugin settings to have the new version, I think if i didn't do that then Maven->Update project would change the System JRE back.